# Show validation message while submitting form with ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

To be particular, in ASP.Net MVC project, I want to show loading image using jQuery when my form post to the server and next action method gets called, as post login, it takes too much time to load the next page.

I tried **onclick()** javascript method on **submit** button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="jsFunction()">
```

Also the **onsubmit()** method of **form**:

```
<form onsubmit="jsFunction"> ... </form>
```

or

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ReadingsEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "jsFunction()" }))
{
```

In case of both, both gets called even there are local validation errors.

I have to show loading img only when the form the getting submitted to server post satisfying the local validation errors.

Any idea in what way this can be achieved?

Comment: Hook to the `submit` event through jQuery, not using the outdated `on*` event attributes. Then, assuming you're using unobtrusive validation, it will work fine.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Tried it, but it's too getting called even if there are client site validation errors. and yes I am using unobstrusive validatoins:
        $("#formLogin").submit(function () {
            alert('hi');
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the `id` attribute value for your form as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ReadingsEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "yourFormId" }))
{
}
```

Now you can check whether your form is valid or not using jQuery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yourFormId").on('submit',function(){
        if($("#yourFormId").valid())
        {
           // here write code to show loading image.
        }
   });
});
```

Make sure that your form view containing following script files:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It worked absolutely fine for me!

Comment: Great to hear that! Welcome.

Comment: Thanks again. I think in MVC "jquery.validate.min.js" & "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" are already added in bundles.

Comment: And that's why I told `Make sure that your form view containing following script files:` If reference from here then no need to add in again here.